# Thread parameters being changed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.5

When starting multiple threads, the `id` parameter I'm parsing is sometimes wrong. Here is my startup:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _threadCount; i++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => WorkerThread(i));
    thread.Start();
    _threads.Add(thread);
}
```

And my thread function:

```
private void WorkerThread(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Thread started {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), id);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
[19:10:54] Thread start 3
[19:10:54] Thread start 9
[19:10:54] Thread start 4
[19:10:54] Thread start 12
[19:10:54] Thread start 11
[19:10:54] Thread start 3
[19:10:54] Thread start 12
[19:10:54] Thread start 6
[19:10:54] Thread start 9
[19:10:54] Thread start 6
[19:10:54] Thread start 13
[19:10:54] Thread start 2
[19:10:54] Thread start 15
[19:10:54] Thread start 9
[19:10:54] Thread start 15
```

Where in my mind, this code should create every thread with a unique `id` instead of duplicates as seen above.

**Compiler info:**

Platform target: x64

Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: All of your threads share the same variable.

Comment: Someone actually just posted a similar question, here is a linked article from Eric Lippert on the subject. http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be careful about accidentally modifying captured variables like `i` after starting the thread, because the `i` is **shared**. The `i` variable refers to the same memory location throughout the loop’s lifetime. The **solution** is to use a *temporary variable* like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _threadCount; i++)
{
      var i1 = i;
      Thread thread = new Thread(() => WorkerThread(i1));
      thread.Start();
      _threads.Add(thread);
}
```

Read more about *Closures* here : [The Beauty of Closures from (*Jon Skeet*)](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) and [Lambda expressions and captured variables from (*Joseph Albahari*).](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread)

Comment: Interesting. I would've thought that passing in a value-type as an argument would do that automatically. Is there some transition period between the function call and when the first line is executed that i could change before it is copied into WorkerThread's argument list?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sources. And yeah @Jakotheshadows i assumed the same

Comment: I guess it makes sense to me now. The function call to WorkerThread doesn't necessarily happen when you do thread.Start();. It could happen at any time during the loop and it is only when WorkerThread gets called in the other thread (perhaps 5 iterations ahead of where the thread was instantiated) that i gets evaluated and copied into the argument list.  The issue here is that i isn't getting evaluated until the thread actually begins.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `i` variable refers to the same memory location through the loop's lifetime. Therefore, each thread calls on a variable whose value may change as it is running. The solution is to user a temporary variable `int temp = i`. as [@Salah Akbari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34319356/2946329) said.

Comment: First `volatile` can only be applied to class or struct fields, not locals.  Second that would not change the fact that the captured variable may be incremented before the previously created thread runs.