# If condition doesn't work in multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written this manager class which holds all loaded bitmaps.
I don't want to store the same bitmap twice, therefore I make a check if I already have a `BitmapHolder` with the same persistence name (`toString()` method of object.)

The problem is, the check in `Add()` will be ignored (or so it seems) even if if shouldn't. This ends up by this class holding several same objects in the list.

```
public class LazyStatic<T> where T : new()
{
    protected static T _static;
    public static T Static
    {
        get
        {
            if (_static == null) _static = new T();
            return _static;
        }
    }
}

public class BitmapManager : LazyStatic<BitmapManager>
{
   private List<BitmapHolder> _bitmaps;

   public BitmapManager()
   {
       _bitmaps = new List<BitmapHolder>();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Will add a loaded bitmap to the internal list.
   /// </summary>
   public void Add(Bitmap b, string persistenceName)
   {
       lock (_bitmaps)
       {
           if (GetBitmap(persistenceName) != null)
               return;
           BitmapHolder bh = new BitmapHolder
           {
               Bitmap = b,
               PersistenceName = persistenceName
           };
           _bitmaps.Add(bh);
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Will run through the internal list and look for a bitmap
   /// with the matching persistence name. Will return target if
   /// exists, otherwise null.
   /// </summary>
   public Bitmap GetBitmap(string persistenceName)
   {
       lock (_bitmaps)
       {
           foreach (BitmapHolder bhs in _bitmaps)
           {
               if (bhs.PersistenceName.Equals(persistenceName))
                   return bhs.Bitmap;
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
```

My question is. How can I prevent the method from 'ignoring' the if condition.

Comment: What's your question? Use a lock.

Comment: You need to use one of the synchronization capabilities .NET offers, like [the lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).  Thread synchronization is a broad topic.  You can start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

Comment: See http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Can you show an example of the persistenceName? Are you sure it is consistent?

Comment: Have a look at this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319303/thread-parameters-being-changed

Comment: @eh. I implemented the lock (see above), but the problem persists.

Comment: @GlenThomas persistenceName is something like 'user_9' and it is the same.

Comment: What does inheriting from `LazyStatic<T>` accomplish, exactly?  It doesn't look like you're even using that code.

Comment: Just use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), if you want thread safety.  Use [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out if an entry is already in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code you are using the BitmapManager class and adding the bitmaps?

Comment: @Raiiy: You don't already see that in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential race condition on the `Static`'s getter, which is not protected by a lock. The race condition could result into creating a duplicate instance of `_static` member and each of the instance would hold a bitmap with the same name. It can be avoided if a static member is instantiated by default:

```
public static class LazyStatic<T> where T : new()
{
    private static T _static = new T();

    public static T Static
    {
       get
       {
          return _static;
       }
    }
}
```

If you would like to defer the instantiation even further:

```
 public static class LazyStatic<T> where T : new()
{
    private static T _static = new Lazy<T>();

    public static T Static
    {
       get
       {
          return _static.Value;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This LazyStatic class looks like an attempt at a singleton design pattern. I think a singleton may actually be what the OP was shooting for.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you have to keep in mind when coding async is that global objects can be changed MID-PROCESS by another thread. Always and always instantiate local objects during multi-threaded operations. Passing in object references used globally will produce unstable results.

Comment: The OP isn't going  to understand this at the level that you're explaining it.

Comment: Certain fundamental programming concepts should be universally understood before implementing multi-threaded UI systems.