# Matrix Multiplication with specific number of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix

I am completely new in the field of multithreading. At the moment I am trying to implement a commandline program which is able to multiply two matrices of equal size. The main goal is that the user can enter a specific number of threads as a commandline argument and that the multiplication task is solved using exactly this number of threads.

My approach is based on the following java implementation which tries to solve a similar task: [Java Implementation Matrix Multiplication Multi-Threading](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198592-matrix-multiplication-multithreading/)

My current state is the following one:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static int rows = 16;
    static int columns = 16;
    static int[] temp = new int[rows*columns];
    static int[,] matrixA = new int[rows, columns];
    static int[,] matrixB =  new int[rows, columns];
    static int[,] result = new int[rows, columns];
    static Thread[] threadPool;

    static void runMultiplication(int index){
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                Console.WriteLine();
                result[index, i] += matrixA[index, j] * matrixB[j, i];
            }
        }
    }

    static void fillMatrix(){
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.GetLength(0); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixA.GetLength(1); j++) {
                matrixA[i, j] = 1;
                matrixB[i, j] = 2;
            }
        }       
    }

    static void multiplyMatrices(){
        threadPool = new Thread[rows];

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            threadPool[i] = new Thread(() => runMultiplication(i));
            threadPool[i].Start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            try{
                threadPool[i].Join();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
             }
        }
    }

    static void printMatrix(int[,] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", matrix[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }       
    }

    static void Main(String[] args){
        fillMatrix();
        multiplyMatrices();
        printMatrix(result);
    }
}
```

At the moment I have two problems:

1. My result matrix contains values which are far from a valid result
2. I do not know if I am on the right way according to my goal that a user can specify how many threads should be used.

I would be very grateful if anyone could guide me to a solution.

PS: I know there are existing posts which are similar to mine, but the main challenge in my post is to allow the user to set the number of threads which will then solve the matrix multiplication.

Comment: The `i` variable refers to the same memory location throughout the loop’s lifetime. Check this answer will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319303/thread-parameters-being-changed

Comment: @HenkHolterman indeed, Parallel.For() would be a much comfortable approach, but I am forced to provide the user the possiblity to define a specific number of threads.

Answer (score 2):

Linear algebra is a difficult place to begin with threads if you're new.  I'd recommend learning about [map/reduce](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) first and implementing that in C#.

Imagine if you have just one core and you wanted to perform a long calculation.  Multiple threads are scheduled by the operating system so that one does some work, then the next is giving a turn, etc.  It's easy to do the thought experiment and figure out that context switching will make the problem go slower than the single threaded version.  There's no true parallelization there.

The problem is that most linear algebra operations are not easily parallelizable.  They aren't independent of each other.  More threads than cores will not improve the situation and may make performance worse.

The best you can do is one thread per core and partitioning the matrix like [this](http://www.math.nyu.edu/~neylon/linalgfall04/project1/dj/multpartmatrices.htm).

Here's a thought: Before you worry about multithreading, take your Matrix class and make sure that every single operation works properly with a single thread.  There's no sense in worrying about multithreading if your code doesn't produce the right answers for a single thread.  Get that working, then figure out how to partition the problem among multiple threads.