# C# Winforms: Why does 'i' output as 2 both times

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, button

So I have the following method:

```
    private void CreateButtons()
    {
        MapFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(UserPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < MapFolders.Length; i++)
        {
            Galleries.Add(new List<Image>());
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = MapFolders[i].Substring(UserPath.Length);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Location = new Point(12, 10 + 39 * (i + 1));
            btn.Width = 200;
            btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                GalleryIndex = i;
                trackBar1.Maximum = Directory.GetFiles(MapFolders[i-1]).Length - 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < trackBar1.Maximum + 1; j++)
                {
                    Galleries.ElementAt(GalleryIndex).Add(new Bitmap(MapFolders[i-1] + "/" + j + ".jpg"));
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = Galleries.ElementAt(GalleryIndex).ElementAt(0);
            };
        }
    }
```

I was expecting the output to be 1 \n 2 but it prints out 2 \n 2 
Why is this the case?

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319303/thread-parameters-being-changed

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This code will have the same behavior in every version of C#.  The semantics of closures did not change at all in C# 5.0

Comment: Because the loop values evaluated in a delegate declared in a loop are the values found when the code is executed, not when the code is declared. If you want the delegate to use a value current at the time the delegate is declared, define a second variable that is not the loop variable, and assign it the loop value. Use that second variable in your delegate.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Servy Oops, he's using a `for` loop, not `foreach`, so the semantics did not change (I had [this change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) in mind).