# Clojuring a value inside a thread method

Tags: c#, multithreading, closures

Hello i am trying to pass the current index of a loop inside a thread lambda method and print it.The method will print only the last value of the index.

```
class Program {
        public static EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        public static EventWaitHandle autohandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        static readonly int ThreadNum=3;

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            object lk = new object();
            new Thread(() => {

                while (true) {

                    var key = Console.ReadKey();
                    if(key.Key==ConsoleKey.A) {
                        handle.Set();
                    } else {
                        handle.Reset();
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);


                }
            }).Start();

            for(int i=0;i<ThreadNum;i++) {

                new Thread(() => {
                    int val = i;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{val} created");
                    while (true) {

                        handle.WaitOne();

                        Console.WriteLine($"From thread:{val}");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }).Start();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

    }
```

Can someone explain to me why would i get only the last value of the index.I understand the index gets clojured (a class gets created which copies the index value) but when the first iteration enters the thread method it should clojure i=0 and keep it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captured Closure (Loop Variable) in C# 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264289/captured-closure-loop-variable-in-c-sharp-5-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread parameters being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319303/thread-parameters-being-changed)

Comment: You are indeed right.This is was what i was expecing..serial code execution regarding what the console prints for the first iteraiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the behaviour you are seeing is because the loop is iterating before the local variable 'val' is assigned.  So by the time the statement

```
int val = i;
```

is executed for the first time, the loop has already iterated 3 times, so you get 'val' set to the last value of i.
When I run it, I get variable behaviour, due to the relative speed at which threads are created.
To get the behaviour I think you want, you need to capture the count of the loop iteration locally, like this.

```
  class Program
  {
    public static EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    public static EventWaitHandle autohandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    static readonly int ThreadNum = 3;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      object lk = new object();
      new Thread(() => {

        while (true)
        {

          var key = Console.ReadKey();
          if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
          {
            handle.Set();
          }
          else
          {
            handle.Reset();
          }
          Thread.Sleep(3000);


        }
      }).Start();

      for (int i = 0; i < ThreadNum; i++)
      {
        int temp = i;
        new Thread(() => ThreadMethod(temp)).Start();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
    private static void ThreadMethod(object obj)
    {
      int val = (int)obj;
      Console.WriteLine($"Thread:{val} created");
      while (true)
      {

        handle.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine($"From thread:{val}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }
```